# How to read data from firebase and append it to an array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a userImages collection and I am trying to read data from it and appending it to my imgUrls array.

This is my code where I read the data from the database and try appending it to my array. Unfortunately, I keep getting an error because the array is apparently empty.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
var ref: DatabaseReference!
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid       //holds the current user uid

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        var imgUrls = [String]()        //array to hold the image urls from the userImages collection

        ref.child("userImages").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in     //read from userImages collection only from the subcollection where the
            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }                       //document Id equals the current user uid. Create a dictionary from the
                                                                                                    //snapshot values

            let values = dict.values        //holds the values from the dictionary

            for value in values {                           //for loop to go through each value from the dictionary
                imgUrls.append((value as? String)!)       //and append to the imgUrls array
            }
        }

        testLabel.text = imgUrls[0]     //I used this to test, but i get an error saying the array is empty
}
```

I posted a question before, but it was so convoluted I decided to delete it and repost it simpler.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are not getting anything in your testLabel.text is because:

```
     ref.child("userImages").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in     //read from userImages collection only from the subcollection where the

     ...

     }
```

is an asynchronous function called. That is it will be done sometimes in the future.

but your:

```
  testLabel.text = imgUrls[0]     //I used this to test, but i get an error saying the array is empty
```

is outside of this call. So the results in "imgUrls" are not available yet.
Put this line inside the function or wait until it has finished before using the results.

Comment: I didn't put it in the question, but that entire code is inside the viewDidLoad() function. I'm new to Swift and firebase. I just started using it about a week and a half or two weeks ago so I'm still getting the hang of it. I'm more familiar with SQL databases currently.

Comment: All the best with Swift and firebase, it's a good combination.
Firebase is basically asynchronous. A good understanding of this is really needed. There is a nice swift related article on this at:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the array before the observeSingleEvent closure is executed. All observation calls to Firebase are asynchronous. This means that you test code is executed before the closure and the array is still empty.

```swift
ref.child("userImages").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in

    // this closure is executed later

    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

    let values = dict.values

    for value in values {
        imgUrls.append((value as? String)!)
    }

    // your test code should bee here
}

// this is executed before closure and the array is empty
testLabel.text = imgUrls[0]
```

For this reason you get the error. You need to add your test code into the closure.

However, there is another catch. Asynchronous calls (their closures) are executed on the background thread.

```swift
ref.child("userImages").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in

  // this is executed on the background thread

}
```

However, all user interface calls must be executed on the main thread. Also wrap your test code by calling the main thread, otherwise you won't see the result in the user interface.

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {

  // this code is executed on the main thread
  // all UI code must be executed on the main thread

}
```

After editing, your code might look like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.lid

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        var imgUrls = [String]()

        ref.child("userImages").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let values = dict.values

            for value in values {
                imgUrls.append((value as? String)!)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                testLabel.text = imgUrls[0]
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Unfortunately, it still didn't work. This is so weird

Comment: @EverNolasco try to add testLabel.setNeedsDisplay() under the last statement like this

DispatchQueue.main.async {
   testLabel.text = imgUrls[0]
   testLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
}